# Python3 доступ к файлу по относительному пути при запуске через символическую ссылку

Tags: python-3.6, скрипт

Не нашёл в поиске ответа на свой вопрос.
Написан скрипт на Python3. Допустим скрипт лежит в /home/test1/Documents/py-script

Скрипт называется script.py и рядом лежит text.txt
Скрипт построчно проходится по txt файлу и обрабатывает кое-что (не важно).

Добавил символическую ссылку в /usr/bin чтобы запускать скрипт из командной строки в любой директории.

Но вот незадача. Когда запускаю скрипт не из директории со скриптом, а по символической ссылке, то почему-то он ищет text.txt в /usr/bin. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так чтобы он искал файл в /home/test1/Documents/py-script  ?

Использовать абсолютный путь пожалуйста не предлагайте, скрипт может лежать в другой директории на другом ПК.

Кусок кода как обращаюсь к файлу

```py
id_file = open("text.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8')encoding='utf-8')
```

---

Написал

```
open(os.path.join(os.path.realpath(__file__), 'text.txt'), "r", encoding='utf-8')
```

Выводит путь верный, но вконце добавляет ещё директорию с названием самого скрипта. Как от этого избавиться?

```
open(os.path.join(os.path.realpath(__file__), '..', 'text.txt'), "r", encoding='utf-8')
```

Тоже не работает

Comment: а чем каталог `/home/test1/Documents/py-script` может отличаться от любого другого каталога?

Comment: Тем что может быть например /home/test1/Привет. Вообще без разницы какой каталог

Comment: ну, если без разницы, используйте упомянутый `/usr/bin`. не подходит? объясните, чем не подходит.

Comment: aleksandr barakin, Вы предлагаете в /usr/bin положить текстовый файл? Это же бред. Не подходит тем, что рядом лежит ещё текстовый файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Для текущего каталога.
open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "id_subscript.txt"), "r", encoding='utf-8')

# Для каталога со скриптом (проход по симлинку).
open(os.path.join(  # Объединить путь.
        os.path.dirname(  # Вернуть имя каталога из пути.
            os.path.realpath(__file__)),  # Путь к файлу, учитывая симлинки.
        "id_subscript.txt"),
    "r", encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Ой извиняюсь. Сейчас прикреплю другой код обращения. Это я уже экспериментировал

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало. Теперь бы понять эту конструкцию. Может кто-нибудь пожалуйста в крации объяснить?

Comment: Раз заработало, нажми кнопку, что ответ решил проблему. Для понимания конструкции прочитай: https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-os-path.html